# Help in identifying IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet, light-sensor

I'm trying to identify the 16 pin white IC shown in the picture but I couldn't find any IC with marking code similar to that. I'm not sure but the board which IC is assembled on may be related to a digital ruler.
Any help will be appreciated.
[image: Board containing the IC]

Comment: This appears to be a CCD or something similar? Or *possibly* an EPROM, but I have some doubts about that.

Comment: There's some chatter about it on [this](https://www.circuitsonline.net/forum/view/113864/3?query=beginnen+met+microcontrollers&mode=or) forum (in dutch). It's a CCD for mechanical measurement systems allowing for a precision of 0.1 micrometer. (Translated from the forum). Some googling indicates it's used in CnC machines.

Comment: 0.1 micron? 100 nm? That seems unlikely. Maybe 0.1 mm?